# Unable to get a value from a json after node fetch in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, rest, get, node-fetch

For My API GET operation, I use node fetch and my code is

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

const HttpProxyAgent = require('http-proxy-agent');
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

fetch('https://threemashery.rb.ipdesign.info/cit1/apigw/tibs/nbrmgmt/NumberManagementService/v1/RetrieveListDNForSelection?apikey=5w8anhcabembfp7tne67rhk8&userID=cpacadm&quantity=2&operatorId=3UK&orderNumber=ORD12341&numberCategory=Normal', {method: 'GET', agent: new 
HttpsProxyAgent('http://10.10.104.4:50683') })
.then(resRaw=>{

    return resRaw.text();


})
.then(resJson=>{

    console.log(resJson);

    console.log(resJson.Header);

})
```

And below are my both console log outputs

```
{"Header":{"ActivityName_T":"AS_DNLogicalResource_NM","MsgType_T":"RESPONSE","msgName":"Error occured while processing request for List DN","Source":"RetrieveListDNLogicalResourceNM","ActivityStatusEnum_T":"FAILURE","ActivityStatus_T":"rcFailure","Timestamp":"2018-07-26T14:45:14.009Z","ProviderInfo":[{"name":"b08359a6-dea1-4e34-9c47-8d5971e1a9dd1532616302405","valueType":"rcFailure","description":"Order is being modified.","Value":{"CharacteristicValue":[{"value":"FAILURE"}]}}]},"Payload":{"NotificationDetails":[{"errorCode":"rcFailure","errorDescription":"Order is being modified."}]}}

undefined
```

Why am I getting as undefined, while I try to take the first element? someone please help me.

Even I tried the below

```
console.log(resJson);
    let res=JSON.stringify(resJson);
    console.log(res);
```

But I am getting like

```
{"Header":{"ActivityName_T":"AS_DNLogicalResource_NM","MsgType_T":"RESPONSE","msgName":"Error occured while processing request for List DN","Source":"RetrieveListDNLogicalResourceNM","ActivityStatusEnum_T":"FAILURE","ActivityStatus_T":"rcFailure","Timestamp":"2018-07-26T14:40:40.189Z","ProviderInfo":[{"name":"4463c84f-4d38-4173-8f11-3b82b2c539a51532616029573","valueType":"rcFailure","description":"Order is being modified.","Value":{"CharacteristicValue":[{"value":"FAILURE"}]}}]},"Payload":{"NotificationDetails":[{"errorCode":"rcFailure","errorDescription":"Order is being modified."}]}}


"{\"Header\":{\"ActivityName_T\":\"AS_DNLogicalResource_NM\",\"MsgType_T\":\"RESPONSE\",\"msgName\":\"Error occured while processing request for List DN\",\"Source\":\"RetrieveListDNLogicalResourceNM\",\"ActivityStatusEnum_T\":\"FAILURE\",\"ActivityStatus_T\":\"rcFailure\",\"Timestamp\":\"2018-07-26T14:40:40.189Z\",\"ProviderInfo\":[{\"name\":\"4463c84f-4d38-4173-8f11-3b82b2c539a51532616029573\",\"valueType\":\"rcFailure\",\"description\":\"Order is being modified.\",\"Value\":{\"CharacteristicValue\":[{\"value\":\"FAILURE\"}]}}]},\"Payload\":{\"NotificationDetails\":[{\"errorCode\":\"rcFailure\",\"errorDescription\":\"Order is being modified.\"}]}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I getting as undefined, while I try to take the first element?

You said `return resRaw.text()` so `resJson` is the text of the response.

A simple string does not have a `Header` property.

You need to `return resRaw.json()` if you want to parse the response as JSON and put the resulting object into `resJson`.

---

> Even I tried the below
>
> ```
> let res=JSON.stringify(resJson);
> ```

That's going in the wrong direction. You're taking the string and then expressing it *in* JSON.

You need to parse the JSON into JavaScript data.